# Searchkick / Elasticsearch exact match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I am using elasticsearch through searchkick

I have a field called "detail" thats analyzed using "standard" analyzer ... now just like in google we do `"several words"` search to get exact match .. can we do the same in searchkick? I am not looking for `fields: [{detail: exact}, name]` because then it will match the whole article ... just the term as a whole not individual words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `match_phrase: true`. You can see it in elastic search [documentation.](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/phrase-matching.html)

But this feature not merged yet in searchkick. FYI: [github pull request](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/pull/412)
I think you can use monkey-patch for add feature to your project.

Answer (score 3):

It's as simple as `User.search "fresh honey", match: :phrase` now.